# Flutter : How to show Progress indicator until the data is fetched from the server

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show a progress indicator until the required data is fetched from the server. Currently what I am doing is made a function getQuotes() that will fetch the data into a variable using setState(). And the Used the FutureBuilder where its future parameter is set to getQuotes(). But this approach gives me a non-ending CircularProgressIndicator. I don't why it is happening. Is ther any problem with the combination of FutureBuilder() and setState() ? Can Some one help ?

Here is my code,

```
Map<String, dynamic> userInfo = {};

  Future<void> getQoutes() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get();
    setState(() {
      userInfo = data.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Some Quotes',
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder (
        future: getQoutes(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error : ${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: 3,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card_fun(userInfo['quotes'][index]);
                          }
                        )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: just pass `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).get()` to your `FutureBuilder` - you dont need that extra `getQoutes` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be to make your `getQuotes()` function returning a `Future<String>` instead of a `Future<void>` and then access the data via the snapshot instead of accessing the state.

The Flutter docs of the `FutureBuilder` [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) are also doing it that way in the demo. As long as you don't need the state of `userInfo` in other places this should be an acceptable solution and you could also remove `userInfo` as variable. If you want to maintain or manipulate it later you could try to put the `setState({})` statement in the `ConnectionState.done` switch case within an `if(snapshot.hasData){}` block.